# Use asterisk/ variables in keyboard shortcuts editor

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, keybindings

I'm using a Mac laptop with an external PC keyboard. Via Apps shortcuts I've redefined some of common shortcuts for Find, Copy Paste actions. However, some applications have dynamic actions names, for instance, Finder shows Copy "filename" action (where filename string is dynamic, obviously). Same goes for several other apps.

**Is it possible to create shortcuts for such menu action items?**

I know it is possible to swap modifier keys, however I would like to change letters as well.